# Separating data in vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I need to store different entities in my vuex-store.
For example Companies, Employees and Workplaces...

These entities are connected by ID-Arrays.

- Company.employees is an array of UserIds
- Employee.workplaces is a list of workplace ids
- ...

I implemented it both ways I know:

- as a single very big store
- with store modules for every entity

The first approach is straightforward but quickly becomes very bloated. The second approach is very clean but data handling is difficult when I need data from 2 stores to fulfill a getter (for example: getWorkplacesByCompany)

What is the preferred way to store such data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modular is definitely better. It avoids the bloat you mentioned and you can always access the data from other modules via the `rootState` or `rootGetters` options passed to the getter functions.

Here's an example:

```js
const employees = {
  state: {
    employees: [
      { id: 1, name: 'Jeff' },
      { id: 2, name: 'Joe' },
      { id: 3, name: 'Jimmy' },
      { id: 4, name: 'Jake' },
      { id: 5, name: 'Jill' },
    ]
  },
}

const companies = {
  state: {
    companies: [
      { id: 1, name: 'Foo Co.', employeeIDs: [ 1, 4, 5 ] },
      { id: 2, name: 'Bar Co.', employeeIDs: [ 2, 3, 5 ] },
    ]
  },
  getters: {
    getCompanyEmployees(state, getters, rootState, rootGetters) {
      return (companyID) => {
        let company = state.companies.find((c) => c.id = companyID);        
        return rootState.employees.employees.filter((e) => {
          return company.employeeIDs.indexOf(e.id) >= 0;
        })
      }
    }
  }
}

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: { employees, companies }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/2.4.0/vuex.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  {{ $store.getters.getCompanyEmployees(1) }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you organize your modules and submodules logically, you can include getters at every level in your store based on where they need data from.  So you might have stores and submodules as so:

```
App
  Blog
    Authors
    Posts
      Tags
```

The getter for `getPostsByAuthor()` would be in the `Blog` module because it needs data from both `Authors` and `Posts`, whereas the getter for `getPostsByTag` could be in the `Posts` module and the getter for `getTagById` could be directly in the `Tag` module.

Comment: If i get this right you suggest to nest stores? I didn't thought about that at all. I would handle your case by having one store with first-level modules. I will dive deeper into nesting stores. That sounds interessting!

Comment: Yes, each store can contain modules that contain more stores https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html

Answer (score 1):

I'd say one store with [namespaced modules](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html) is the right approach. You still have access to sibling modules.
So in your getter you'd pass `rootState` as your third argument and access a sibling namespace like `rootState.Employee.someData`.

See more https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/api.html